# rvm 'gem install' wants to install latest gems. Can it be set to automatically install the latest compatible versions?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm making a simple ruby script with a gem.  My rvm is set to ruby 2.1.1.  I'm installing the selenium-webdriver gem (but the specific gem isn't important).

I'm getting frustrated because as I try to install selenium-webdriver it is asking me to install each dependency of a lower compatible version instead of automatically choosing the latest compatible version of the gem and all dependencies.

So if I type in `gem install selenium-webdriver` it returns this:

*Fetching selenium-webdriver-3.142.6.gem
Fetching rubyzip-2.0.0.gem
Fetching childprocess-3.0.0.gem
ERROR:  Error installing selenium-webdriver:
    The last version of childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.0.1. Try installing it with gem install childprocess -v 1.0.1 and then running the current command again*

Of course I can follow the suggestion and go through this process again installing each dependency, but isn't there a way to do this automatically?  I had thought that is what rvm is for, right?  This doesn't happen in my Rails apps, so why should it happen outside of Rails?  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Having a Gemfile and using bundler instead of installing gems manually would solve this issue. This kind of problems is the exact reason why bundler was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gems have dependencies that may not be compatible with older versions of ruby (have methods that appeared in later versions of ruby). If you need to put this gem on your ruby version, you need to create a gemfile manually and register versions that are compatible with the new gem. Or install an older gem selenium-webdriver that fits Your version of ruby